# ObjectionJS relationship modelClass is not defined

Tags: node.js, objection.js

I'm trying to update a relationship between a `user` and `user_profile`.  I can update the user, but I keep getting this error when I try to update the `user_profile`:

`ERROR: Error: UserProfile.relationMappings.user: modelClass is not defined`

As far as I can tell I've mimicked the example from the docs, and TypeScript example, but can anyone see why this isn't working?

I included the query, both models, and the user profile migration. The contents of the BaseModel are commented out so it is equivalent to inheriting from Model directly, and the `jsonSchema` is only for validation so I removed them for brevity.

**UPDATE**

Removing the `relationshipMappings` from `UserProfile` stops the error from occurring, but since I need the `BelongsToOneRelation` relationship I'm still trying.  At least it seems to be narrowed down to the `relationMappings` on the `UserProfile`.

**Query**

```
const user = await User.query() // <--- Inserts the user
  .insert({ username, password });

const profile = await UserProfile.query() <--- Throws error
  .insert({ user_id: 1, first_name, last_name });
```

**Models**

```
import { Model, RelationMappings } from 'objection';
import { BaseModel } from './base.model';
import { UserProfile } from './user-profile.model';

export class User extends BaseModel {
  readonly id: number;
  username: string;
  password: string;
  role: string;

  static tableName = 'users';

  static jsonSchema = { ... };

  static relationMappings: RelationMappings = {
    profile: {
      relation: Model.HasOneRelation,
      modelClass: UserProfile,
      join: {
        from: 'users.id',
        to: 'user_profiles.user_id'
      }
    }
  };

}

import { Model, RelationMappings } from 'objection';
import { BaseModel } from './base.model';
import { User } from './user.model';

export class UserProfile extends BaseModel {
  readonly id: number;
  user_id: number;
  first_name: string;
  last_name: string;

  static tableName = 'user_profiles';

  static jsonSchema = { ... };

  static relationMappings: RelationMappings = {
    user: {
      relation: Model.BelongsToOneRelation,
      modelClass: User,
      join: {
        from: 'user_profiles.user_id',
        to: 'users.id'
      }
    }
  };
}
```

**Migration**

```
exports.up = function (knex, Promise) {
  return knex.schema
    .createTable('user_profiles', (table) => {
      table.increments('id').primary();

      table.integer('user_id')
        .unsigned()
        .notNullable();
      table.foreign('user_id')
        .references('users.id');

      table.string('first_name');
      table.string('last_name');

      table.timestamps(true, true);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would say that

a) it is problem of circular dependency or/and 
b) there is problem with import paths

One is to use absolute file paths in modelClass instead of constructors. For example

```
 modelClass: __dirname + '/User'
```

or

```
modelClass: require('./User').default
```

look at example at:
https://github.com/Vincit/objection.js/blob/master/examples/express-es7/src/models/Animal.js

Comment: Thanks for reply, modules in TypeScript can't have circular dependencies, but I did try this just in case :)  Seems to be related to the relationship specifically on the UserProfile

Comment: yea, so I mean instead to import User in UserProfile module define modelClass as path to module :) I think that should help - here is example in TS - look modelClass of owner relationship

Comment: Thanks you were totally right.  It's funny the error doesn't describe the issue.  I'd never have figured that out based on the error.  The final solution was `${__dirname}/user.model` and the same for `user-profile.model` in case anyone wants to know exactly the code that worked.